# How do I duplicate a mail template

Tags: civimail, message-templates, custom-templates

I have an existing email template I have made and now I want to repurpose it for another use while keeping the basic layout. How can I duplicate my original template please?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the button to display the source code and then copy all.

Open a new template, click on the (same) button to display the source code, and paste what you have copied. Then click on the button again, and voilá, you have copied an email template!